# Highlight all elements above in RibbonSplitButton

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to replicate the Visual Studio (and probably others) feature that highlights all elements that appear above the item that the mouse is on in a list.

[image: VisualStudioImage]

(Note the mouse is positioned over the 6th line from the top).  As shown, the undo commands 1-5 are highlighted when the mouse is over the 6th element.

Currently, I am trying to get an idea of what to do in a dummy application before implementing it in my actual program.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430535/highlight-multiple-items-in-listbox) solution but it uses a listbox and doesn't work with how I am adding items as I am adding items dynamically.  Here is what I have so far:

In my XAML:

```
<TextBox Width="60" Margin="2" Text="{Binding SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<RibbonSplitButton Label="Add" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding addToStack}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddedItems}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="2" Padding="2" Name="AddRSB" MouseOverBackground="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" MouseMove="RibbonSplitButton_MouseMove">
    <RibbonSplitButton.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonMenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedBelow}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="MouseOverBorderBrush">
                          <Setter.Value>
                              <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"/>
                          </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                      <Setter Property="MouseOverBackground">
                          <Setter.Value>
                              <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.1"/>
                          </Setter.Value>
                       </Setter>
                       <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                           <Setter.Value>
                               <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"/>
                           </Setter.Value>
                       </Setter>
                       <Setter Property="Background">
                           <Setter.Value>
                               <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </RibbonSplitButton.Resources>
</RibbonSplitButton>
```

In my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<CustomRibbonMenuItem> _add = new ObservableCollection<CustomRibbonMenuItem>();
public IEnumerable<CustomRibbonMenuItem> AddedItems
{
    get
    {
        return _add;
    }
}
private string _sometext;
public string SomeText
{
    get
    {
        return _sometext;
    }
    set
    {
        _sometext = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SomeText));
    }
}
public DelegateCommand<object> addToStack => new DelegateCommand<object>((o) => AddNum(o));
public void AddNum(object o)
{
    int.TryParse(SomeText, out int num);
    var crmi = new CustomRibbonMenuItem(num);
    _add.Insert(0, crmi);
    SomeText = string.Empty;
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AddedItems));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AddHasContent));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RemoveHasContent));
}
```

(`DelegateCommand` uses `ICommand`, `RaisePropertyChanged` uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`).  My `CustomRibbonMenuItem` class:

```
private bool _selectedBelow = false;
public int Number { get; set; }
public bool SelectedBelow
{
    get { return _selectedBelow; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _selectedBelow)
            return;

        _selectedBelow = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedBelow));
    }
}

public CustomRibbonMenuItem(int number)
{
    Number = number;
    SelectedBelow = false;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return Number.ToString();
}
```

And finally, in my code behind:

```
private void RibbonSplitButton_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var itemSelected = false;
    for(int i = AddRSB.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var currentItem = AddRSB.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as RibbonMenuItem;
        if(currentItem != null)
        {
            if (itemSelected)
            {
                ((CustomRibbonMenuItem)currentItem.DataContext).SelectedBelow = true;
            }
            else if(IsMouseOverItem(currentItem, e.GetPosition(currentItem)))
            {
                ((CustomRibbonMenuItem)currentItem.DataContext).SelectedBelow = true;
                itemSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ((CustomRibbonMenuItem)currentItem.DataContext).SelectedBelow = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the items above the item that the mouse is over have a fade on the left side.

[image: WeirdFading]

If I remove the `MouseOver...` properties, all of the highlighted parts seem to flicker between highlighted and not highlighted.  How do I get rid of the faded part?  Is there a better way to implement this feature (`RibbonSplitButton` and the `MouseMoveEvent` seem like the best option for what I am trying to accomplish)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set Template property in the RibbonMenuItem style and you should no longer get gradient effect:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Width="auto"
                    MinWidth="50"
                    CornerRadius="3"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           Padding="15,3"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           TextAlignment="Left"
                           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Works like a charm!  (Will award bounty when I am able to)